# Omnibus 7.10.0 Gitlab Redirect https to http

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

```
https://mydomainName.com --> AWS-ELB [ingress 443 --> egress 80]) --> OmnibusGitlab
```

Now Omnibus redirects to the following and times out

```
http://mydomainName.com/users/sign_in
```

Any way to debug this issue.

Comment: What solution have you used then ?

Answer (score 0):

Full path has to be in https because if you are going forward via reverse proxy that accepts https and the you have to come back as as https.

Separate the Nginx configuration because Omnibus solution have to constrains that block the flexibility we have on standard nginx. 
Do the following to make this change:

```
edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and add

```
 nginx['enable'] = false
 web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data'] #for ubuntu nginx user
 web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']   # for centos 6-7
```

Add the following configuration to enable gitlab via simple nginx
    /etc/nginx/site-availabe/server

```
server {
  listen *:443 default_server ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myserver.key;
  server_name myhostname.com
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
  client_max_body_size 50m; #or 5000 
  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx_error.log;
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
}
location @gitlab {
  proxy_read_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
  proxy_connect_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://gitlab;
}
error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

gitlab-redirect

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab-redirect 
server {
listen  80;
server_name myhostname.com;
return 301 https://myhostname.com;
}
```